# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__

Tags: python

I want to display this:

---

Number    Name

1         Jane

2         Linda

3         Vladimir

---

but when I put row in the last line its giving me an error.

```
output = cursor.fetchall()

for row in output:
    print("{0:20}\t{1:20}".format("Number", "Name"))
    print("{0:20}\t{1:20}".format(row, row[0]))
```

Comment: You need `enumerate` here and you need to pull that first print out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my limited testing, Python's f-strings and .format (tested with 3.8) do not support strings like `"{:2}".format([0])` (i.e. with arguments of list type). If you do need a list printed out, convert it to `str`:

```
rows = [[1, "Jane"], [2, "Linda"], [3, "Vladimir"]]
print("{0:16}{1:8}".format("Number", "Name"))
for row in rows:
    print("{0:<16}{1:8}".format(str(row), row[1]))
```

Or just pass each element separately:

```
rows = [[1, "Jane"], [2, "Linda"], [3, "Vladimir"]]
print("{0:8}{1:8}".format("Number", "Name"))
for row in rows:
    print("{0:<8}{1:8}".format(row[0], row[1]))
```